# Spring boot: accessing all git source properties available to a microApplication

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot

so I have a micro ap named microap-auth created in spring boot.
All my config properties are available in `application.properties` (available globally to all microAps) and `microap-auth.yml` available to just one microAp only.
I need to create a groovy service in microap-auth that would check if a given property is available in git for that micro app.

For this purpose, how can i fetch all the properties available to that microap in git source ? I think these are available in "Environment" bean provided by Spring.
I tried the following:

```
@Autowired
Environment env

def propertyMap = env.getProperties();
```

however, this doesn't work for me as `propertyMap` is always returned null.

Is there a way I can achieve my goal here ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you wanna do, but check this link below to read values from application.properties or application.yml

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html